# ¿Cual es el uso real de los modificadores acceso en programación?

Tags: java, poo

Ya se que son para especificar la accesibilidad a variables, constructores y métodos pero lo que nunca me han explicado, ni siquiera en cursos de programación es ¿por que es util usarlos? ¿no sería mas sencillo poner todo como public y así evitar restricciones?

Answer (score 3):

cuando hablamos de programar utilizando el paradigma de la **Programación Orientada a Objetos**, hablamos de  brindarle modularidad a nuestro código, seguridad y una estructura escalable, entre varias cosas.

Todo esto viene de la mano con los pilares de la POO: ***polimorfismo, encapsulamiento y herencia***.

El caso de los  ***modificadores de acceso***  se corresponde mucho al encapsulamiento, y nos permiten manejar de que manera se va a acceder a cierta función/atributo de una clase. Nos va a permitir manejar el flujo de trabajo que se le va a dar a nuestro código para que haga realmente lo que queremos que haga y que se ejecuten la líneas que teníamos previstas ante cierto evento.

Aquí un ejemplo:

Si tenemos una clase Persona :

```
    public class Persona {
       private String nombre;
       private int idRandom;

       public Persona() {
          this.idRandom = Math.random()*10;
       }

       public setNombre(String nombre) {
         this.nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
       }

       public String getNombre() {
          return this.nombre;
       }

       public int getIdRandom() {
          return this.idRandom;
       }
    }
```

Podemos notar que declare todos los atributos de Persona como `private` ya que solamente quiero que se pueda acceder a ellos a través de los métodos que yo programé para ello, y no que al instanciar una nueva Persona puedan hacer algo como lo siguiente : `Persona p = new Persona();  p.nombre = "fraNcO";`. *(Notemos la mezcla de mayúsculas y minúsculas).*

Al declarar privado el atributo `nombre` claramente dejo expresado que se debe utilizar el método set (el cual es publico) para realizar la asignación de X valor a mi atributo `nombre`.

Realizando `p.setNombre(String nombre)` el método se encargará  de asignar el valor a la variable y de pasar a mayúscula el mismo, permitiendo así normalizar ese dato para dejarlo uniforme, a mi criterio (pensando por ejemplo en una futura persistencia en base de datos).

En cuanto al `idRandom` (tambien privado) no le permito ningún tipo de seteo (ya que no hay métodos públicos que accedan a él) y solamente opero mediante el constructor, dándole un valor aleatorio entre 0 y 10 (se generará automáticamente al instanciar una nueva Persona), en este caso el usuario no puede interferir para cambiarme esa secuencia.

Como vemos la utilización de modificadores de acceso me permite realmente dominar mi código y de realizar operaciones que sin ellos serían imposibles de realizar, a no se que apelemos a la buena voluntad del usuario (nunca jaja). Te invito a que veamos patrones de diseño como Singleton para que entiendas un poco mas ejemplos prácticos de como utilizar los modificadores de acceso. Saludos! espero te haya servido,.

Comment: Felipe si la respuesta te sirvió recuerda darle el tilde!